# strcat using pointers

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any better suggestions for this c functions copyString,concatString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431425/any-better-suggestions-for-this-c-functions-copystring-concatstring)

I'm trying to write strcat using pointers, I can't change the main().

```
void str_cat(char **s1,char *s2) {
   while(**s1)
      *(s1++); /* go to the end of string1*/

   /* copy string 2 at the end of string 1*/
   while(*s2)
      *(s1++) = (s2++);
   puts(*s1);
 }
```

I call the function from the main as follow:

```
char *str = NULL;
str_cat(&str, " World!");
```

The problem is when I try to get to the end of s1, but it's not incrementing correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Multiple issues:
If s1 is NULL, where should the output be concatenated? plus `*(s1++)` needs to be changed to `(*s1)++`; plus `*(s1++) = (s2++)` needs to be changed to `*((*s1)++) = *(s2++)`

Comment: Learn to enable all warnings and debugging info at compilation time, and to use the debugger. On Linux, that means compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, improve the code till you got no warnings, and use  `gdb` (perhaps also `valgrind`) to debug.

Comment: @anishsane: Thanks, I did it and I get an error in runtime when the program gets to the second while, to the ((*s1)++) = *(s2++) line.

Answer (score 2):

Your function assumes that `s2` can be appended at the end of `s1`. So `s1` should be big enough to accommodate `s2`.

You are passing `s1` as NULL and de-referencing a NULL pointer, which is undefined behavior.

Also there is really no need to pass the address of a character pointer in your case.

Comment: +1 for getting to the nub of the matter. The broken dereferences are the lesser issue (but just as broken).

Comment: Huh? Isn't it `s1` that needs to be big enough, being the destination?

Answer (score 1):

```
*(s1++); /* go to the end of string1*/
```

That increments the `char**`, and the dereference operation does nothing there. You want to increment the pointed-to `char*`, so you'd need

```
(*s1)++;
```

(similar for `s2`.)

However, you probably don't really want to change the pointer in the caller, so you should use a temporary variable

```
char *temp = *s1;
```

and increment that to find the end of the first string, or, better pass a `char*` in the first place.

And of course, you should only call it with pointers to actual 0-terminated strings.

Comment: OK thanks, incrementing in the first part works OK but in the second loop the assignment just override s1 instead of adding the string.

Comment: Of course you have to change that part too. `*temp++ = *s2++;` or, if you don't use a temporary `char*`, `*(*s1)++ = *s2++;`.

Comment: I did it already but I get an error during runtime. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an **Undefined Behavior**.
You are writing to a pointer which does not point to valid memory. `str` does not point to any valid memory it points to `NULL`.

It is your responsibility that `str` points to a valid and large enough memory to hold the contents you are copying to it, if not the result is an Undefined Behavior and a non-standard conforming program which means anything behavior is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have.

```
  char * strcat (char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *dp;
    char *sp = (char *)src;

    if ((dest != NULL) && (src != NULL))
    {
        dp = &dest[strlen(dest)];

        while (*sp != '\0')
        {
            *dp++ = *sp++;
        }
        *dp = '\0';
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the main(), so destination has to be pointer to pointer. thanks.

Comment: Surely you can take the above and work out how to dereference it to do what you need?