# Implementation of strcpy and strcat that get a reference of a pointer bug

Tags: c, string, strcpy, strcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any better suggestions for this c functions copyString,concatString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431425/any-better-suggestions-for-this-c-functions-copystring-concatstring)

This is a question form a job interview , I need to implement it with a specific signature this is the code I need to work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *str = NULL;
    new_strcpy(&str , "string one");
    new_strcpy(&str , str +7);
    new_strcat(&str , " two");
    new_printf(&str , "%str !", s);
    puts(str ); 
    new_free(&str);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my implementation to new_strcpy:

```
char* new_strcpy(char **dst,const char *source)
{

  char *ans=*dst;

  while(**dst++=*source++);

  return ans;

}
```

But this solution crash, can someone help me ?

Comment: `**dst++` use parentheses for everyone sake.

Comment: "This is a question form a job interview" -- sorry, but you should not have told them you know C.

Comment: maybe the interviewee mentions the benefits of code re-use and how one should aim to allocate and free heap memory in the same scope rather than offsetting them by reinventing existing functions in a less elegant form (in other words its not a very good interview question)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your solution is that you fail to allocate memory for `*dst`.

Consider the first three lines of the code that needs to work:

```
char *str = NULL;
new_strcpy(&str , "string one");
new_strcpy(&str , str +7);         // ***
```

From this, it is clear that:

1. `new_strcpy()` needs to allocate memory for the result.
2. When allocating `str` anew, `new_strcpy()` needs to deallocate the previous `str` to avoid leaking memory.
3. To make line `***` above work, the deallocation has to happen *after* the allocation.

Here is a skeleton implementation to give you the idea. I implement the functions in terms of `strcpy()` et al, but if calling the library function is not permissible, you can write your own loops (you already know how to do that).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void new_strcpy(char** dst, const char* src) {
    char* orig_dst = *dst;
    *dst = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
    strcpy(*dst, src); /* replace with a loop if calling strcpy() is not permissible */
    free(orig_dst);
}

void new_strcat(char** dst, const char* src) {
    char* orig_dst = *dst;
    *dst = malloc(strlen(*dst) + strlen(src) + 1);
    strcpy(*dst, orig_dst); /* replace with a loop if calling strcpy() is not permissible */
    strcat(*dst, src);      /* ditto for strcat() */
    free(orig_dst);
}

void new_free(char** dst) {
    free(*dst);
    *dst = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = NULL;
    new_strcpy(&str , "string one");
    new_strcpy(&str , str +7);
    new_strcat(&str , " two");
/*    new_printf(&str , "%str !", s); */
    puts(str );
    new_free(&str);
    return 0;
}
```

I leave implementing `new_printf()` as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: free(orig_dst); is wrong. with that you will lose the memory of *dst. you should not free memory in that stage.

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: You are completely missing the point. See how the functions are used in the OP's `main()`.

Comment: the question is to develop an alternate function of `strcpy` and not use strcp in the `new_strcpy` function

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: And for `new_printf()` the task is what, to write your own `printf()` from scratch?

Comment: @Lundin: Have you looked at the code in any detail?

Comment: @NPE for the `new_printf()`. the exercice is not to print on the screen but is to print on a destination string. so it could be done from scratch ;-)

Comment: I don't think this is returning a pointer to garbage land - orig_dst is free'd, dst is returned, after the call to malloc these point to different things - looks ok to me

Comment: Looks ok to me too now. So I removed my answer.

Comment: @NPE: when you use this instruction "free(orig_dst)", you lose the returned value (because you have this instruction "char* orig_dst = *dst")

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI: `*dst` gets re-assigned between the two lines that you quote.

Comment: Is it the official troll day or something?

Comment: Ok so it doesn't return a garbage pointer, but it assumes that it gets a pointer to dynamic memory, and then returns an allocated chunk of memory which isn't going to be freed unless you call a custom free function. The code is so obscure I don't see how it would be of any use in a real world application. A sane implementation would be similar to strdup.

Comment: I guess the interviewer want to see if the candidate can handle heap memory and can use pointer the right way. Its not the question if this is a real world problem. For example I would let pass the candidate if he/she is able to give the right ideas. No need to write the code untile the end.

Comment: @NPE. You are right, the free does not cause loose of the new malloc because it free the old buffer.

Comment: @Lundin yes its the question not the solution which is at fault here